# Integration of Jenkins with Xray with the help of Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, jira-xray

I am getting this issue on the integration of Jenkins with Xray using Jenkinsfile. Error:-

Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed! Status:400 Response:{"error":"Error assembling issue data: project is required"}.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please share if you are using JIRA in cloud or in Server? Can you also share how are you pushing the results to Xray in the Jenkinsfile?

Meanwhile please confirm that you are passing the projectKey parameter if you are using an API call like described here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-JUnitXMLresults.

Comment: Hi Cristiano, I am using JIRA on server. I am sharing you the Jenkinsfile and cucumber report.json file. You can look over it and check the issue

Comment: environment {
    //def readpom = ""
    def description = "[BUILD_URL|${env.BUILD_URL}]"
    def labels = '["QA","Release1"]'
    def environment = "Dev"
    def testExecutionFieldId = 12502
    def testEnvironmentFieldName = "customFieldId_14124"
    def projectKey = "RTRB"
    def xrayConnectorId = 'f94aa6c1-d97a-47c1-9aa4-b7a73098b32f'
    def info = '''{
          "fields": {
              "project": {
              "key": "''' + 'projectKey' + '''"
            },

Comment: "labels":''' + 'labels' + ''',
             "description":"''' + 'description' + '''",
             "summary": "Automated Regression Execution @ ''' + 'env.BUILD_TIME' + '' + 'environment' + ''' ",
             "issuetype": {
             "id": "''' + 'testExecutionfieldId' + '''" 
              },
             "''' + 'testEnvironmentFieldName' + '''" : [
             "''' + 'environment' + '''"
             ]
             }
             }'''

  }

Comment: stage('Import results to Xray') {
      steps {
        echo info
        dir('KarateRTR'){
        step([$class: 'XrayImportBuilder', endpointName: '/cucumber/multipart', importFilePath: 'target/karate-reports/applicationTesting.XrayJenkins.RTRB-4711.json', importInfo: info, projectKey:'RTRB', inputInfoSwitcher: 'fileContent', serverInstance: xrayConnectorId])
      }}
    }
  }

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are using the endpointName: '/cucumber/multipart', when using this endpoint Xray expects either:

- One file with the test results in json format and a second json configuration file where you configure other values (use inputInfoSwitcher: filePath and importInfo: <file_path>)
- One file with the test results in json format and a json text with the extra configurations you want to pass to Xray ((use inputInfoSwitcher: fileContent and importInfo: <json_text>)

Notice that if the values of the configuration file or the json text are not correct they will not be used.

In the above case it seems that you are not correctly replacing the values in the json text.

You can find more info here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins#IntegrationwithJenkins-Pipelineprojectssupport

Comment: Thanks a lot Cristiano :) It is working fine by using /cucumber/multipart end point. And I was wrongly taking the variables value in info block. I have corrected it by using in this format ${projectKey} and now it works with this format. Thanks again :)